# Кодировка текстовых файлов

Tags: java, файлы, кодировка, utf-8, текст

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой: при считывании из текстового файла, русские символы преобразовывались в '�', при том, что раньше такого не было.

В самих текстовых файлов возможности сменить кодировку нет.
   Методом научного тыка, определил, что кодировка сменилась на "windows-1251".

```
BufferedReader fileRead1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(fileName1), "windows-1251"));
```

Причем у всех старых файлов осталась кодировка "UTF-8", тогда как новые создаются с "windows-1251", то есть, что бы корректно считать два файла, приходится извращаться:

```
BufferedReader fileRead1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(fileName1), "windows-1251"));
BufferedReader fileRead2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(fileName2), "UTF-8") );
```

Вопрос: Как сменить кодировку по дефолту у файла? Можно ли динамически узнать кодировку файла?

Comment: UTF-8 кодировка задаётся 3-х байтной "меткой" вначале файла EF BB BF. В 1251 такой "шапки" нету.

Comment: Для определения кодировки на лету обратите внимание на библиотеку juniversalchardet. Вполне сносно определяет кодировку файла. Иногда, правда, определяет WINDOWS-1251 как MACCYRILLIC или KOI8-R.